# Is it ok to make API calls from useEffect in a Next.js App?

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

So I'm kind of new to Next.js and I have a question about API calls.

From what I noticed API calls should be made in getServerSideProps and its variations. But I wonder if it is totally wrong to make API calls from inside a react component using the useEffect hook. I mean, will that API call break the whole point that Next.js is trying to do (having static pages)?

Comment: You don't need to use getServerSideProps or any other specific Next.js data-fetching features. It is not going to break anything, but you should read the Next.js documentation to acknowledge what you're loosing, especially if you need to prefetch data before rendering the component. (edit) If you want to go full-static you need to use these features, but if you're good with leaving only parts of the page static - you don't need to.

Comment: The only reason to do this is if the component is non immediately required. For example if the component needs to be lazy loaded when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.